# What's the purpose of the CIL nop opcode?

Tags: assembly, bytecode, cil

I'm going through MSIL and noticing there are a lot of [nop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.nop.aspx) instructions in the MSIL.

The MSDN article says they take no action and are used to fill space if the opcode is patched. They're used a lot more in debug builds than release builds.

I know that these kinds of statements are used in assembly languages to align later instructions, but why are MSIL nops needed in MSIL?

(Editor's note: the accepted answer is about machine-code NOPs, not MSIL/CIL NOPs which the question originally asked about.)

Comment: There is mass confusion in these answers between the MSIL nop instruction emitted by the language compiler into the assembly and the x86 nop instructions (on that platform) emitted by the JIT compiler when the assembly is run.  [In fact the accepted answer is about x86 nops, and has no relation to MSIL.]  

Ideally this question should get split into 2 different questions: purpose of MSIL::nop? and purpose of native platform nop?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

NOPs serve several purposes:

- They allow the debugger to place a breakpoint on a line even if it is combined with others in the generated code.
- It allows the loader to patch a jump with a different-sized target offset.
- It allows a block of code to be aligned at a particular boundary, which can be good for caching.
- It allows for incremental linking to overwrite chunks of code with a call to a new section without having to worry about the overall function changing size.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP): "A NOP is most commonly used for timing purposes, to force memory alignment, to prevent hazards, to occupy a branch delay slot, to render void an existing instruction such as a jump, or as a place-holder to be replaced by active instructions later on in program development (or to replace removed instructions when refactoring would be problematic or time-consuming). In some cases, a NOP can have minor side effects; for example, on the Motorola 68000 series of processors, the NOP opcode causes a synchronization of the pipeline."

Answer (score 12):

Here's how [MSIL / CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions) nops (**not x86 machine code [`nop`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/nop)**) are used by debugging:

Nops are used by language compilers (C#, VB, etc.) to define implicit sequence points. These tell the JIT compiler where to ensure machine instructions can be mapped back to IL instructions.

Rick Byer's blog entry on [DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints](http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2005/09/08/462676.aspx), explains a few of the details.

C# also places Nops after call instructions so that the return site location in source is the call out rather than the line after the call.

Comment: _C# also places Nops after call instructions so that the return site location in source is the call out rather than the line after the call._  Not sure whether I get this. Do you have any reference available?

Answer (score 9):

It provides an opportunity for line-based markers (e.g. breakpoints) in the code where a release build would emit none.

Comment: Do breakpoints need to be on a nop? Why not just put a breakpoint on the regular opcode?

Comment: a lot of regular opcodes get optimized away in release builds. That would mess up your breakpoints unless there was a placeholder nop there the breakpoints would still point to

Comment: In debug builds, they're also used to provide an instruction to break on where the code has no instruction.  Opening braces, for example.

Comment: You may want to add a reference to http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/17/4422794.aspx as a source.

Comment: Well, thanks Greg and Jimmy for making this into an actual answer.

Answer (score 6):

Dude!  No-op is awesome!  It is an instruction that does nothing but consume time.  In the dim dark ages you would use it to do microadjustments in timing in critical loops or more importantly as a filler in self-modifying code.

Comment: I understand its use when its being run on the directly on hardware, but MSIL is JITed.

Comment: MSIL is only JITed on systems that have JIT - MSIL doesn't demand JIT.

Comment: Also handy for code injection for whatever intended purpose, be it a patch, improvement, or things like cracks, as you can replace them with an arbitrary jump to execute whatever other code you like without having to worry as much about possible side effects (vs replacing "real" instructions), when you only have a compiled assembly or binary. Such modifications will of course invalidate authenticode signatures, if any exist.

Answer (score 6):

It may also make code run faster, when optimizing for specific processors or architectures:

Processors for a long time employ multiple pipelines that work roughly in parallel, so two independent instruction can be exceuted at the same time. On a simple processor with two pipelines, the first may support all instructions, whereas the second supports only a subset. Also, there are some stalls between the pipelines when one has to wait for the result of a previous instruction that isn't finished yet.

Under these circumstances, a dedicated *nop* may force the next instruction into a specific pipeline (the first, or not the first), and improve the pairing of following instructions so that the cost of the *nop*  is more than amortized.

Answer (score 5):

In one processor I worked for recently (for four years) NOP was used to make sure the previous operation finished before the next operation was started. For instance:

load value to register (takes 8 cycles)
nop 8
add 1 to register

This made sure register had the correct value before the add operation.

Another use was to fill in execution units, such as the interrupt vectors which had to be a certain size (32 bytes) because address for vector0 was, say 0, for vector 1 0x20 and so on, so the compiler put NOPs in there if needed.

Answer (score 4):

They could be using them to support **edit-and-continue** while debugging.  It provides the debugger with room to work to replace the old code with new without changing offsets, etc.

Comment: I implemented the debugger support in VS for Edit and continue (I did not implement the CLR or compiler parts).  Nops are part of the story to ensure correct mappings from old to new version of a method (specifically in the cases of jumps out of exeception handling code).  However, replacing the MSIL is done on a whole function basis. For CLR managed code it is not necessary to 'leave room' in the msil to accomplish that part.  What you say here is correct with respect to native Edit and continue.

Answer (score 4):

50 years too late but hey.

Nop's are useful if you are typing assembly code by hand.
If you had to remove code, you could nop the old opcodes.

similary, you could insert new code by overwriting some opcode and jump somewhere else. There you put the overwritten opcodes, and insert your new code. When ready you jump back.

Sometimes you had to use the tools which were available. In some cases this was just a very basic machinecode editor.

Nowadays with compilers the techniques make no sense whatsoever anymore.

Answer (score 3):

One classic use for them is so that your debugger can always associate a source-code line with an IL instruction.

Comment: Since msil is JIT compiled when run it is possible to lose that mapping (e.g. native instruction has no unique MSIL instruction).  NOPs are used as a communication mechanism from the language compiler to the JIT compiler to preserve such a mapping.

Answer (score 3):

In the software cracking scene, a classic method to unlock an application would be to patch with a NOP the line that checks for the key or registration or time period or whatnot so it would do nothing and simply continue starting the application as if it is registered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure no-op instructions weren't invented to help people pirate software :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've also seen NOPs in code that modifies itself to obfuscate what it does as a placeholder (veeery old copy protection).

Answer (score 3):

As ddaa said, nops let you account for variance in the stack, so that when you overwrite the return address it jumps to the nop sled (a lot of nops in a row) and then hits the executable code correctly, rather than jumping to some byte in the instruction that isn't the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat unorthodox use are [NOP-Slides](http://www.phreedom.org/solar/honeynet/scan20/scan20.html), used in buffer overflow exploits.

Comment: was looking for this :)

Comment: Correct Your Link ,  it is not working , please always make sure , you submited web archive link , because they wont give 404 don't found.

Comment: Currently working on shellcode and wanted more context on NOP. Had to go back a bit but here's an archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20110124015428/http://www.phreedom.org:80/solar/honeynet/scan20/scan20.html

Answer (score 1):

They allow the linker to replace a longer instruction (typically long jump) with a shorter one (short jump). The NOP takes the extra space - the code could not be moved around as it would stop other jumps from working. This happens at link-time, so the compiler can't know whether a long or short jump would be appropriate.

At least, that's one of their traditional uses.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your specific question, but back in the old days you could use a NOP to fill a [branch delay slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_delay_slot), if you couldn't manage to fill it with an otherwise-useful instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Do the .NET compilers align the MSIL output?  I'd imagine it might be useful for speeding up access to the IL...  Also, my understanding is that it's designed to be portable and aligned accesses are required on some other hardware platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The first assembly I learned was SPARC so I'm familiar with the branch delay slot, if you can't fill it with another instruction, usually the instruction you were going to put above the branch instruction or increment a counter in loops, you use a NOP.

I'm not familiar with cracking, but I think is common to overwrite the stack using NOP so you have not to exactly calculate where your malicious function begins.

Answer (score 1):

I used NOPs to automagically adjust the latency accumulated after entering an ISR. Very handy to nail timing dead on.